# Is there a way to deserialize json date object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following object

```
{
"date":"2019-07-22 16:16:45.000000",
"timezone_type":3,
"timezone":"America/Sao_Paulo"
}
```

i need to convert it to a JavaScript Date. If i try JSON.parse it says "invalid date".

I'd rather not have turned it into a json at all, but it is part of a bigger object that i need serialized whole.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access it as you know it:

```js
const o = {
  "date":"2019-07-22 16:16:45.000000",
  "timezone_type":3,
  "timezone":"America/Sao_Paulo"
}
const date = new Date(o.date)
console.log(date)
const now = new Date()
console.log(now)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

**note:** of course you can also read those other values and pass it to the Date object

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible solution:

```
var str = "2019-07-22 16:16:45.000000"
var date = new Date(str);
```